# In R data.table find time intervals between two different tags in time, tag- data

Tags: r, dplyr, data.table

I have a tabular log file with the (simplified) structure: `<time>, <event_tag>` and want to find intervals between two different `event_tags`, `problem` and `all fine`. The difficulty is that `all fine` and also `problem` is repeated regularly.
So the algorithm by hand would be to find the first `problem` and look for the next `all fine` and proceed until the last `problem` and subsequent `all fine`.

Sample dataset:

```
library(data.table)
set.seed(156125)
DT <- data.table(time = seq(as.POSIXct(tz = "UTC", "2024-01-01"), 
                            as.POSIXct(tz = "UTC", "2024-01-10"), 
                            by = "12 hours"),
                 event_tag = c("problem", "all fine")[round(runif(19, 1.2, 2.49))])

# time                    event_tag
# <POSc>                     <char>
#  1: 2024-01-01 00:00:00  all fine
#  2: 2024-01-01 12:00:00  all fine
#  3: 2024-01-02 00:00:00   problem
#  4: 2024-01-02 12:00:00  all fine
#  5: 2024-01-03 00:00:00  all fine
#  6: 2024-01-03 12:00:00   problem
#  7: 2024-01-04 00:00:00   problem
#  8: 2024-01-04 12:00:00  all fine
#  9: 2024-01-05 00:00:00  all fine
# 10: 2024-01-05 12:00:00  all fine
# 11: 2024-01-06 00:00:00  all fine
# 12: 2024-01-06 12:00:00  all fine
# 13: 2024-01-07 00:00:00   problem
# 14: 2024-01-07 12:00:00  all fine
# 15: 2024-01-08 00:00:00  all fine
# 16: 2024-01-08 12:00:00   problem
# 17: 2024-01-09 00:00:00  all fine
# 18: 2024-01-09 12:00:00  all fine
# 19: 2024-01-10 00:00:00  all fine
```

Desired result:

```
data.table(problem_start = DT$time[c(3, 6, 13, 16)],
           problem_end = DT$time[c(4, 8, 14, 17)])

#          problem_start         problem_end
#                 <POSc>              <POSc>
# 1: 2024-01-02 00:00:00 2024-01-02 12:00:00
# 2: 2024-01-03 12:00:00 2024-01-04 12:00:00
# 3: 2024-01-07 00:00:00 2024-01-07 12:00:00
# 4: 2024-01-08 12:00:00 2024-01-09 00:00:00
```

I thought about some solution by making the two tags `boolean` and use `cumsum`, but could not figure it out completely. And maybe there is a neat `data.table`-way to do it which I don't see at the moment. However, I would also be happy with a `dplyr` solution even though I prefer `data.table`.

```
DT[ , bool := ifelse(event_tag == "all fine", 0, 1)]
DT[ , cumsum(bool)]
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is a different `data.table` approach (although I prefer the rolling join solution)

```
DT[DT[, .I[1], by = rleid(event_tag)]$V1
   ][, end_time := shift(time, type = "lead")
     ][event_tag == "problem", ]
```

Functionality:

- create groups of consecutive event_tag (`rleid()`), select the first row of each group (`.I[1]`)
- endtime is the first row of the next group/row (`shift()`)
- select only the problem-rows

NB: requires the original data to be sorted (or keyed) on `time`

Comment: very nice, I was trying to get the `rleid`-effect but missed the use if `.I[1]`

Comment: I've just crossed with another `rleid` alternative (using `first` rather than `.I[1]`). The shift-and-filter used here is much neater than pivoting as I did.

Answer (score 3):

You can do a rolling join of the candidate end times onto the candidate start times, then take the earliest start time associated with each joined end time:

```
result <- 
  # candidate end times
  DT[event_tag=="all fine", .(time, problem_end = time)      
     # rolling right-join of candidate start times onto them
     ][DT[event_tag=="problem", .(time)], on=.(time), roll=-Inf
       # take earliest start time per end time
       ][, .(problem_start = first(time)), by=problem_end]   

result |> setcolorder(c("problem_start")) |> setorder(problem_start)

> result
         problem_start         problem_end
                <POSc>              <POSc>
1: 2024-01-02 00:00:00 2024-01-02 12:00:00
2: 2024-01-03 12:00:00 2024-01-04 12:00:00
3: 2024-01-07 00:00:00 2024-01-07 12:00:00
4: 2024-01-08 12:00:00 2024-01-09 00:00:00
```